# Can You Add Data to Database (supabase) without an Server using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I'm kinda new in programming and I'm learning how the web works, And Im working on this project using Supabase PostgreeSQL with Api, so what I want to do is write (send data to db), and I want to do it using only ReactJS but I don't know if this is possible, I have made something to work only with JS and the API keyes from SUPABASE, but I don't know if this is correct to do

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import {supabase} from '../db/supabase';
import Helmet from "helmet";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div``
const LeftContainer = styled.div``
const RightContainer = styled.div``
const Input = styled.input``
const BtnButBlack = styled.button``
const BtnButGreen = styled.button``
const Form = styled.form``

export default function Signup() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        new_account({email: email, password: password}, name, username)
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleEmail = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setEmail(event.target.value)
    };

    const handlePassword = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    }
    const handleName = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setName(event.target.value)
    }
    const handleUsername = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setUsername(event.target.value)
    }

    const new_account = async ({email, password}) => {
        const {user, session, error} = await supabase.auth.signUp({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        })
        if (error) {
            console.error(error)
            return
        }
        console.log(user);
        await supabase
            .from('Users')
            .insert([
                {username: username, name: name, email: email, password: password}
            ])
    };

    return (
        <Container>
            <LeftContainer>
                Signup
            </LeftContainer>
            <RightContainer>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Input onChange={handleUsername} type="text" value={username} placeholder="Username" autoComplete="false" /><br></br>
                    <Input onChange={handleName} type="text" value={name} placeholder="Name" autoComplete="false" /><br></br>
                    <Input onChange={handleEmail} type="text" value={email} placeholder="Email" autoComplete="false" /><br></br>
                    <Input onChange={handlePassword} type="password" value={password} placeholder="Password" autoComplete="false" /><br />
                    <BtnButGreen>Sign Up</BtnButGreen>
                </Form>
            </RightContainer>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

and this is the supabase module that you can import and use it on the jsx file:

```
import {createClient} from '@supabase/supabase-js'
const supabaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
```

Comment: This is not a good idea cause everyone can read your API credentials if you put them in JS.

Comment: React runs in browser environment, most DB-sdk cant run  there and yes as @ClausBönnhoff stated - your DB will be available for everyone to access.

Comment: I don't understand how if i store the keys on .env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have seems great! With Supabase, the you are only exposing anon key and supabase URL, which are meant to be public.

You use row level security and Supabase Auth to prevent malicious attackers to hack your database. You can read more about row level security here:
https://supabase.io/docs/learn/auth-deep-dive/auth-row-level-security

If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: so if i use .env then i will be fine

Comment: @neyeror358
Using .env is typically the way to go, but even when you use .env, you are exposing the Anon key and Supabase URL to the world, which is fine. Serverless technologies like Supabase or Firebase are designed so that you can expose these keys/URLs to the world as long as you have the correct security setup. For Supabase, that would be to set up row level security that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: So it doesn't come with security by default?

Comment: Supabase is a secure database even if you expose anon key and url as long as you set security policies. With security policy, you can tell Supabase which data can be access by who and which data can't. You can read about how to set security policy for your Supabase database here: https://supabase.io/docs/guides/auth#policies